# The parameterized query expects the parameter @Date

Tags: c#, sql-server, asp.net-mvc

Pretty new to C# and this is my first time asking for help on this so go easy on me.

I'm trying to pass the inputted date to SQL Db but keep getting an error message that reads:
The parameterized query expects the parameter '@Date', which was not supplied.'

What exactly is the problem with this? Is it simply the formatting of the date being passed through that's causing the error or something else entirely? I've tried adding a format tag to the controller like mm/dd/yyyy but that didn't help.

DAL

```
using GopherDirt.Models;
using Microsoft.Data.SqlClient;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Options;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace GopherDirt.DataAccessLayer
{
    public class DALEvent
    {
        private readonly IConfiguration configuration;
        public DALEvent(IConfiguration config)
        {
            configuration = config;
        }

        internal bool AddEvent(EventModel eventModel)
        {
            // Connect to Database
            string connStr = configuration.GetConnectionString("ConnString") ;
            using SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(connStr);
            conn.Open();

            // Command
            string query = "INSERT INTO [dbo].[Event] ( [EventType], [Title], [Date], [Location], [Company])" +
                " VALUES( @EventType, @Title, @Date, @Location, @Company) select SCOPE_IDENTITY() as Id";
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query, conn);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@EventType", eventModel.EventType);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Title", eventModel.Title);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Date", eventModel.Date);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Location", eventModel.Location);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Company", eventModel.Company);

            // Query DB
            SqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
            reader.Read();

            // Close Connection
            conn.Close();
            return true;
        }
    }
}
```

Controller

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Configuration;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using GopherDirt.DataAccessLayer;
using GopherDirt.Models;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;

namespace GopherDirt.Controllers
{
    public class AddEventController : Controller
    {
        private readonly IConfiguration configuration;

        public AddEventController(IConfiguration config)
        {
            configuration = config;
        }

        public IActionResult AddEventToDB(EventModel eventModel)
        {
            DALEvent DALevent = new DALEvent(configuration);

            bool eventPost = DALevent.AddEvent(eventModel);

            return View("Index", eventPost);
        }
    }
}
```

Model

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace GopherDirt.Models
{
    public enum EventType
    {
        Festival, TrailBuild, Race, Demo
    }

    public class EventModel
    {
        // Figure out the db generated ID's

        [Key]
        [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
        public int Id { get; set; }

        [Display(Name = "Event type")]
        [Required(ErrorMessage = "Please give an event type.")]
        public EventType EventType { get; set; }

        [Display(Name = "Title")]
        [Required(ErrorMessage = "Please give an event title.")]
        public string Title { get; set; }

        [DataType(DataType.Date)]
        [Display(Name = "Date")]
        [Required(ErrorMessage = "Please give a date and time.")]
        public DateType Date { get; set; }

        [Display(Name = "Location")]
        [Required(ErrorMessage = "Please give a location")]
        public string Location { get; set; }
#nullable enable
        public string? Company { get; set; }

    }
}
```

SQL

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Event] (
    [Id]        INT          NOT NULL,
    [EventType] VARCHAR (50) NOT NULL,
    [Title]     VARCHAR (50) NOT NULL,
    [Date]      DATE   NOT NULL,
    [Time]      VARCHAR (20) NOT NULL,
    [Location]  VARCHAR (50) NOT NULL,
    [Company]   VARCHAR (50) NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([Id] ASC)
);
```

Comment: Is `eventModel.Date == null`?

Comment: Do you mean can it be null? I have it as a required input.

Comment: And what is `DateType` (the declared type of the `Date` property)?

Comment: No, I mean *is* it null when you put a breakpoint on the line where that parameter is added. When `SqlParameter.Value` is `null`, it's as if the parameter wasn't supplied. You need `DBNull.Value` to convey `NULL` to the server.

Comment: That is my intention. Is that not the proper declaration of the type I need?

Comment: It is null when I put the breakline. But if the value is required and to not be excepted when null, do I still us DBNull.Value?

Comment: You don't need to worry about translating `null` to `DBNull.Value` if the field is required. But then you *do* need to ensure you have a value, which clearly hasn't happened. I'm not familiar with this `DateType` type; just a guess here, but it seems ASP.NET doesn't know how to bind a value to that type, so it probably can't enforce `[Required]`. Change it to `DateTime` for now.

Comment: Also, [some important reading](https://blogs.msmvps.com/jcoehoorn/blog/2014/05/12/can-we-stop-using-addwithvalue-already/) for you to consider and apply to your work.

Comment: `[DataType(DataType.Date)] ` creates a dropdown calendar to pick your date when running the app.  I tried deleting it and simply typed a date like so `12122020` into the field and it still returned as null.

Comment: I'm famliar with that but that's not what I'm talking about. I'm referring to the declared type of the property: `public DateType Date { get; set; }`  <-- `DateType` here. Change that to `DateTime`, at least until you have it working.

Comment: @madreflection that did it. Thank you! I'll take a look at the article as well.